# createRecognizer in java Sphinx

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sphinx4

When I checked Oracle docs for javax.Speech.Recognizer class I found this statement which describes createRecognizer method.
"Create a **Recognizer** with specified required properties. If there is no Recognizer with the required properties the method returns null."
What is mean here by **if there is no recognizer**? Don't we create a new recognizer here?

Answer (score 0):

No recognizer means "no recognizer for the required properties". For example you might request a recognizer for French while implementation supports only English. Then you will get null.